# How to remake one array into two smaller via C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, copy

I need to make from one 10-element array two 5-element arrays. I made code like this

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    const int size1 = 10, size2 = 5;

    int array[size1]{ 1,3,6,2,82,10,6,34,2,5 }, arb[size2]{}, arc[size2]{};

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        arb[i] = array[i];
    }
    for (size_t i = 5; i < 9; i++) {
        
        for (size_t e = 0; e < 4; e++)
        {
            arc[e] = array[i];
        }
        
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << arb[i] << "\t";
    }
    cout << endl;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << arc[i] << "\t";
    }
}
```

But the second array gives "2 2 2 2 0". I haven`t any ideas how to fix this.

Comment: Just a hint: do you really need loop nesting for something this simple?

Comment: Why are you using a nested loop? The outer loop runs `9 - 5 = 4` times and the inner loop runs `4 - 0 = 4` times for EACH iteration of the outer loop. So it'll run 16 times.

Comment: Looks like you tried using nested loops to account for the offset of the second array. You can simply use something like the first loop, but include an offset to `array`. Example : `arc[i] = array[i+5];`. All though, it may be better to instead just generate ranges with pairs of pointers.

Comment: Got to wonder why you define `size2 = 5;` and use it here `arb[size2]{}` but don't use it here `for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++)`. It's better to write `for (size_t i = 0; i < size2; i++)`, and the same for your other loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These nested loops

```
for (size_t i = 5; i < 9; i++) {
    
    for (size_t e = 0; e < 4; e++)
    {
        arc[e] = array[i];
    }
    
}
```

do not make a sense. Moreover there are used unknow magic number `9` and `4`. In fact all elements of the array `arc` except the last element are set to the value of the element `array[8]` that is to the value of the element of the array `array` used in the last iteration of the outer loop.

The program can look the following way

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    const size_t size1 = 10, size2 = 5;

    int array[size1]{ 1,3,6,2,82,10,6,34,2,5 }, arb[size2]{}, arc[size2]{};

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < size2; i++ )
    {
        arb[i] = array[i];
    }
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < size2; i++ )
    {
        arc[i] = array[i + size2];
    }
    
    for ( const auto &item : arb )
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    
    std::cout << '\n';
    
    for ( const auto &item : arc )
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    
    std::cout << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 3 6 2 82 
10 6 34 2 5
```

Or instead of the loops you could use the standard algorithm `std::copy` and `std::copy_n`. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    const size_t size1 = 10, size2 = 5;

    int array[size1]{ 1,3,6,2,82,10,6,34,2,5 }, arb[size2]{}, arc[size2]{};

    std::copy_n( std::begin( array ), size2, std::begin( arb ) );
    std::copy_n( std::next( std::begin( array ), size2 ), size2, std::begin( arc ) );
    
    for ( const auto &item : arb )
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    
    std::cout << '\n';
    
    for ( const auto &item : arc )
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    
    std::cout << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is the same as shown above.

```
1 3 6 2 82 
10 6 34 2 5
```

Comment: Thank you, very much!

Answer (score 4):

Unless you have a specific reason that these *must* be arrays (which is extremely rare, at least in my experience), I'd use `std::vector`s instead. This makes it trivial to initialize the smaller "arrays" with the correct pieces of the larger one:

```cpp
std::vector<int> array { 1,3,6,2,82,10,6,34,2,5 };
std::vector<int> arb { array.begin(), array.begin() + size2};
std::vector<int> arc { array.begin() + size2, array.end() };
```

This also makes it easy to (for one example) split the main array in half, regardless of its exact size:

```cpp
std::vector<int> array { 1,3,6,2,82,10,6,34,2,5, 12, 17, 92, 101, -3 };
auto half = array.size() / 2;
std::vector<int> arb { array.begin(), array.begin() + half};
std::vector<int> arc { array.begin() + half, array.end() };
```

[As it stands right now, this will make the second half the larger one if the main array has an odd number of elements, but if that's not what you want, you can change the computation of `half` to suit your needs.]

Comment: I personally try to avoid curly braces for non-initializer-list contruction with types that have an initializer list constructor. It is easy to get in that habit and accidentally construct a list of two objects instead using whichever constructor you intended. For example `std::vector<int> v{2, 3};` instead of `std::vector<int>(2, 3);`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Fair enough (though fortunately for iterators, even braces do the right thing).

Answer (score 1):

You did mistake in second loop by iterating second time, in such way after this loop you set only last element in new array ...

Here is the proper version of the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  const int size1 = 10, size2 = 5;

  int array[size1]{ 1, 3, 6, 2, 82, 10, 6, 34, 2, 5 };
  int arb[size2]{};
  int arc[size2]{};

  for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    arb[i] = array[i];
  }
  for (size_t i = 5; i < 10; i++) {
    arc[i-5] = array[i];
  }

  for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    std::cout << arb[i] << "\t";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;

  for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    std::cout << arc[i] << "\t";
  }
}
```

Also I would suggest simpler version of the code with `std::copy`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  const int size1 = 10, size2 = 5;

  int array[size1]{ 1, 3, 6, 2, 82, 10, 6, 34, 2, 5 };
  int arb[size2]{};
  int arc[size2]{};

  std::copy(&array[0], &array[5], arb);
  std::copy(&array[5], &array[10], arc);

  for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    std::cout << arb[i] << "\t";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;

  for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    std::cout << arc[i] << "\t";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the nested `for` loop

```
for (size_t i = 5; i < 10; i++)
{ 
    //essentially what you're doing in this loop is that for each element 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 
    // for the first loop you are assigning for instance arc[0] till arc[3] to be all equal to array[5]
    // so whats happening is n=by the time you reach arc
    // take care you are assigning only 4 elements

    for (size_t e = 0; e < 4; e++)          // size here 
    {
        arc[e] = array[i];
    }

}
```

An alternative is to do this:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < size2; i++)
{
    arc[i] = array[i+5];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets try the dirty variant, O(1)

**Warning this will explode in your face if array goes out of scope before arb or arc**

```
int main() {
    const int size1 = 10, size2 = 5;

    int array[size1]{ 1,3,6,2,82,10,6,34,2,5 };
    int *arb = array, *arc = &array[size2];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < size2; i++) {
        cout << arb[i] << "\t";
    }
    cout << endl;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < size2; i++) {
        cout << arc[i] << "\t";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `memcpy` to copy an array of plain old value types.

```
memcpy(arb, array, size2);
memcpy(arc, array+size2, size2);
```

Both of those statements replace your two for-loops.

`memcpy` function is available by declaring `#include <string.h>` at the top of your source file.

Comment: Or even better, imho, std::copy from algorithm.